# Check if path exists that contains a set of N nodes

Tags: python, networkx, path-finding

Given a graph `g` and a set of N nodes `my_nodes = [n1, n2, n3, ...]`, how can I check if there's a path that contains all N nodes?

1. Checking among `all_simple_paths` for paths that contain all nodes in `my_nodes` becomes computationally cumbersome as the graph grows
2. The search above can be limited to paths between `my_nodes` pairwise couples. This reduces complexity only to a small degree. Plus it requires a lot of python looping, which is quite slow

Is there a faster solution to the problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a path that contains _only_ those N nodes? All all N nodes and perhaps some other nodes?

Comment: @DYZ All N nodes, with or without any other nodes that are not comprised in `my_nodes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try out some greedy algorithm here, starting the path find check from all the nodes to find, and step by step explore your graph. Can't provide some real sample, but pseudo-code should be something like this:

- Start `n` path stubs from all your `n` nodes to find
- For all these path stubs adjust them by all the neighbors which weren't checked before
- If you have some intersection between path stubs, then you got a new one, which does contain more of your needed nodes than before
- If after merging the stub paths you have the one which covers all needed nodes, you're done
- If there are still some additional nodes to add to the path, you continue with second step again
- If there are no nodes left in graph, the path doesn't exists

This algorithm has complexity `O(E + N)`, because you're visiting the edges and nodes in non-recursive fashion.

However, in case of directed graph the "merge" will be a bit more complicated, yet still be done, but in this case the worst scenario may take a lot of time.

**Update**:

As you say that the graph is directed, the above approach wouldn't work well. In this case you may simplify your task like this:

- Find the [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in graph (I suggest you to implement it by yourself, e.g., [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm)). The complexity is `O(E + N)`. You can use a [NetworkX method for this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.component.html#module-networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected), if you want some out-ofbox solution.
- Create the condensation of graph, based on step 1 information, with saving the information about which component can be visited from other. Again, there is a [NetworkX method](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.condensation.html) for this.
- Now you can easily say, which nodes from your set are in the same component, so a path containing all of them definitely exists.
- After that all you need to check is a connectivity between different components for your nodes. For example, you can get the [topological sort of condensation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html) and do check in linear time again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try to implement

Comment: @Pythonic in general, if your graph is not directed, it's a simple `dfs` task

Comment: Yes, the graph is directed. It is a grammar of sorts, for combination of certain token words. Given a random input of these words, I need to recombine them

Comment: Great answer, wish I could give it a +10. Lot of work to do now, thanks!

Comment: VMAtm have a look at this as well if you have any suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623236/networkx-how-to-represent-edge-conditional-to-path

Comment: @Pythonic yeah, I saw that but for now don't know the answer. Maybe will find something.